# How to force WPF textboxes contents to be displayed above other controls similar to excel cells

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

I have an ItemsControl that contains a textbox for each binding item and I want to allow overlaying text box content if its content is wider than the textbox width similar to excel cells overlaying behavior.
Is there a way to do this?

[image: 1]

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce the excel cells overlay behavior by using a Grid with dynamic column count using this helper dependency properties https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/ as a container template of ItemsControl and binding the column index of each textbox to the ordered item index and binding Grid.ZIndex to the reversed index to be displayed above the adjacent text boxes.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" helpers:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding MyCollection.Count}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ItemIndex}"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ReversedIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding MaxMergedCells}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox MinWidth="30" Text="{Binding }"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tooltip for that. You just need to bind the source with itself.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStringCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For further information:

[DrawToolTip Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawtooltipeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

[Set ToolTipSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.popupeventargs.tooltipsize?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: This won't allow inserting wide text content because it won't be fully visible after exceeding the textbox width.

Comment: You can set the tooltip size. I would use the drawtooltip event. The size of the tooltip can be generated dynamically with the length of your text.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I need to increase the width of the textbox itself while filling its contents without moving the adjacent textboxes similar to excel cells.

Comment: We all need programs that do what we want without telling them.

Answer (score 1):

To replicate a similar behavior, you can make use of a `Popup`.

To implement a similar behavior, you first must disable content wrapping of your `TextBox`.
Then replace the current `TextBox` with a `TextBlock`, which is used to display the text.
The `Popup`, which actually contains the editable `TextBox`, will then overlay this `TextBlock` at the exact position, thus hiding the `TextBlock` to make it appear to stretch and overlay the adjacent items.
A `MultiTrigger` will close the Popup as soon as the focus moved outside the `ListBoxItem`.

To improve performance you should use the `VirtualizingStackPanel` as items host.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyStringCollection}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Width="800">
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
        <Popup x:Name="EditableTextSiteHost"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TextSite}"
               Placement="Relative"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=TextSite, Path=ActualHeight}"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=EditableTextSite}">
          <TextBox x:Name="EditableTextSite"
                   Text="{Binding TextData}" />
        </Popup>
      </Grid>

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
                       Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                       Value="True" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter TargetName="EditableTextSiteHost"
                  Property="IsOpen"
                  Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">

      <!-- Make items overlap -->
      <Setter Property="Margin"
              Value="-2,0,0,0" />
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="50" />

      <Style.Triggers>

        <!-- Apply zero Margin on the first item -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Margin"
                  Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

### To-do

This is just a raw example, a proof of concept. You would have to improve the behavior. For example, you would want to close the `Popup` when the user scrolls or moves the `Window`. Otherwise, since `Popup` itself is a `Window`, the `Popup` would not move to follow the placement target. You could move the related logic to an attached behavior.
You likely also want to improve the selection behavior. Currently the selection highlight border does not (virtually) extend to surround the Popup. You have to mimic this by applying a Border on the `TextBox` that will replicate the `ListBoxItem` highlight border.